# Issues with array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a list of inputs like this...

[image: Inputs]

The blue area is where user names would be listed. The input fields are for adding players. Each user has a total of 13 players. I am having difficulties figuring out how I can `INSERT` a particular player and assign it to that user. I was told I could do this with arrays.

I have always struggled with arrays and am not sure how to do this. I created this as an attempt, but do not know what to do next or if this is even correct.

```
<?php
$playerArray = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt)) {
$playerArray[] = $row['player_name'];
}
?>

<input class="draftBorder" value='<?php echo $player1; ?>'/>
            <input name="$playerArray[]" "class="draftBorder" value='<?php echo $player2; ?>'/>
            <input name="$playerArray[]" class="draftBorder" value='<?php echo $player3; ?>'/>
            <input name="$playerArray[]" class="draftBorder" value='<?php echo $player4; ?>'/>
            <input name="$playerArray[]" class="draftBorder" value='<?php echo $player5; ?>'/>
            <input name="$playerArray[]" class="draftBorder" value='<?php echo $player6; ?>'/>
            <input name="$playerArray[]" class="draftBorder" value='<?php echo $player7; ?>'/>
            <input name="$playerArray[]" class="draftBorder" value='<?php echo $player8; ?>'/>
            <input name="$playerArray[]" class="draftBorder" value='<?php echo $player9; ?>'/>
            <input name="$playerArray[]" class="draftBorder" value='<?php echo $player10; ?>'/>
            <input name="$playerArray[]" class="draftBorder" value='<?php echo $player11; ?>'/>
            <input name="$playerArray[]" class="draftBorder" value='<?php echo $player12; ?>'/>
            <input name="$playerArray[]" class="draftBorder" value='<?php echo $player13; ?>'/>
```

Am I going about this the correct way with the array? How would I `INSERT` this with the array to be associated with the user the player was entered under?

Comment: If you're going to display pure HTML among PHP script, stop the interpreter before start HTML tags with `?>` or use output functions like `echo`

Comment: Problem with `"` after the second input and you forgot to close the php tag avec the while

Comment: Sorry just typed this up really quickly just to see if I am going in the right direction.

Comment: There is a lot of errors: **1)** you do not need to iterate over `$row` and pass it to another array, since itself is an array already. **2)** your first input does not have a name **3)** all your inputs have the same name. You should use bracketed-ending names when you're dealing with multiple values input nature like `select` and stuff. `inputs` must have individual names **4)** there is no `form` tag wrapping your inputs together for an HTTP request to send it ahead a processing page, so it will basically do nothing.

Comment: @AedixRhinedale Could you explain that in a little more detail. Especially number 2 because I assigned names to them?

Comment: @Paul `<input class="draftBorder" value='<?php echo $player1; ?>'/>`. First of all, there is no `type` property defined (what kind of input is that? HTML assumes it's a "text" type when there is none, but it's good practice to define it since there's a lot of types). It goes for all other inputs. Then the `name` property will be the key to your `$_POST` or `$_GET` array that'll receive your data at PHP side. Without name, you shall receive nothing.

Comment: What do you want `$playerArray[]` to be ? Like how many records ?

Comment: This was explained to me and it is what I am trying to do..."The answer to how you associate a set of form fields with the user they belong to, is to use, guess what, an array for the form field name. See this link - PHP: PHP and HTML - Manual

You would assign your own keys to the array entries and either use the user_id as the array key and the player_id as the value (assuming you have the players defined in a table) for fields running down the page or use the player_id as the array key and the user_id as the value for form fields running across the page."

Comment: I want the playerArray to be the players for the users. I want to be able to type in a player in any input and that player be recognized for that user and inserted into my db

Comment: And you want to send it all at once? Like `Array [5] ( [user_1] => Array [13] ( [0] => player11, [1] => player12, ... ), [user_2] => Array ( [0] => player21, [1] => player22... ), ... )` -- something like this structure?

Comment: Yes, something like that. I will be entering a player name in one at a time. So I would do user1 player1, user2 player1, user2 player1, user1 player2,etc. After each player has been typed in, I will be submitting each time a player name is typed in. So I guess I will be re-submitting the info for the past entries.

Comment: Ok I don't understand so 'ill explain the basics of arrays. Arrays are multidimentional values, like matrix in math. For example it can have "player1" and "player2". You can't echo it because it means nothing. You can echo the first element like `$playerArray[1]` or the element named player1 like `$playerArray['player1']`. So, named an input as an array also means absolutly nothing

Comment: I am not wanting to echo the array. I want the array to be used to gather the text I am entering in that field (if that is possible). I am doing a `SELECT` query above to output the player. I am trying to figure out a way to `INSERT` the text in the input and associate it with the user.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't understand how to use array. Is this helping you ?

```
$i = 1;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt)) {

$playerArray = $row['player_name'];
$valueInput = $player."".$i;
echo "<input name='$playerArray' 'class='draftBorder' value='$valueInput'/>";
$i++;
}
```

For all players in your query you'll have an input which value will be $player1, $player2 etc.

I think you want them to be `text` type. You better type your inputs

Comment: That makes a little bit more sence, but would that actually send the value to the correct value to the player I need to associate it with? Also what is the $i++ for? You are correct, I don;t understand arrays that well and that is why I am having so much trouble.

Comment: Yes, each values are different. Look, the first one is $player1, the second one $player2 etc. `$i++` is a shortcut for `$i=$i+1` in php

Comment: I have a question, are you sure `$player1`, `$player2`, `$player3` exist ? because they're variables you know because they have a `$`